# Simple GPU programming (with Cg?)

Tags: c++, gpu, gpgpu, cg

I am eager to find out how to use the parallel processing power of GPUs. However, I am NOT eager to make graphics! I tried the tutorial of Cg, but it seems heavy with graphics terms. Furthermore, I can't seem to grasp how I can connect such a program to some input and output.

Let us consider the following very simple program, that could obviously benefit from parallelism(ignore slow HDD speed): Read two big integer arrays from 2 files, make a new array by adding the elements of the last two, and store it in another file. I didn't test it, but thats how I would code it in c++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;


int main(void)
{
    const int N=10000000;
    int a[N],b[N],c[N];
    ifstream a_source ("file_a",ios::binary);
    ifstream b_source ("file_a",ios::binary);
    ofstream c_target ("file_a",ios::binary);

    a_source.read((char*)a,N*sizeof(int));
    b_source.read((char*)b,N*sizeof(int));

    for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
        c[i]=a[i]+b[i];

    c_target.write((char*)c,N*sizeof(int));
    return 0;
}
```

Can you please elaborate how I can use Cg for this?

Comment: Are you dead set on Cg? As far as I remember it’s purely a shader language and hence not necessarily suited for general purpose GPU programming. Have a look at CUDA or OpenCL instead. (Caveat: your particular example is of course a trivial shader but I still think it makes more sense to use a general purpose API instead of one developed for graphics).

Comment: Cg is C for graphics, not C for GPU. If you want to do GPGPU with it you'll need to know how graphics processing works and how you can map GPGPU on it.

Answer (score 2):

[Cg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cg_%28programming_language%29) is really for shaders, you'd be better off using [CUDA](http://www.nvidia.com/object/cuda_home_new.html), however if you are dead set on using Cg with fragment shaders, have a look at [this](http://cg.alexandra.dk/2009/04/29/easy-gpgpu-program-opengl-and-cg/) basic example (2D grid based computation).

Comment: +1 The problem is that Cg/GLSL are shading languages, i.e. they requires the user to learn OpenGL to be able to transfer data from the PC's RAM to the GPU. The OP should really investigate CUDA which hides all this complexity. But as far as I remember, CUDA is only available on NVIDIA's GPUS.

Comment: CUDA is only available for nVidia GPUs, the cross-GPU platform version of it is *OpenCL* (from the makers of OpenGL).

Comment: I chose CUDA just cause it was an nVidia product like Cg and has great tools and tutorials :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to have a look at C++ AMP http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2011/06/15/introducing-amp.aspx

In general you need to be aware that speedups are minimal when you use double precission compared to teh extra efford you need to put into your code. This is when you compare to a 6 core SSE solution that can be turned on with a compiler switch (and mauybe using VTune from Intel for performance anaysis)